# Array not printing correct Values

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying read numbers from a text file and store it into an array.
When I try to read the numbers that are in the array, the output is slighty off.
This is my code:

```
struct point{
    double x[7];
    double y[7];
}point;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data_2.txt", "r");
    struct point points;
    int len = 8;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double total = 0;
    int left=0;
    int right=0;
    int line = 0;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &points.x[i],&points.y[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < len;i++)
        printf("looking at point %.2f %.2f\n",points.x[i],points.y[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

the Test file I use contains the following digits

```
  2.3  7.5
  7.6  7.1
  8.5  3.0
  5.9  0.7
  1.0  2.0 
  5.1  5.8
  4.0  4.5 
  4.3  3.4
```

The output I get is this:

```
looking at point 2.30 4.30
looking at point 7.60 7.10
looking at point 8.50 3.00
looking at point 5.90 0.70
looking at point 1.00 2.00
looking at point 5.10 5.80 
looking at point 4.00 4.50
looking at point 4.30 3.40
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's strange. Try closing the file, once it's usage is completed in function.

Comment: You have a overflow of array indexes. Array `x, y` in struct point can only hold 7 numbers, but you are trying to write into 8. Expanding the array size will fix it.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf).

Comment: You should check if `fopen` actually is able to open the file. i.e. does not return NULL

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your struct isn't big enough to store 8 numbers and it's invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You have `double x[7]` but you're looping to 8.

Why you're getting that specific behavior, and I can reproduce it here on OS X, I'm not sure. But that's undefined behavior for you.

Answer (score 3):

Update your struct like this:

```
struct point{
    double x[8];
    double y[8];
}point;
```

This will help you read and display the data correctly.
[example-with-stdin](http://ideone.com/SXewDR)